# std::setw() considering special characters as two characters

Tags: c++, c++11, special-characters, iomanip, setw

Why is std::setw() considering special chars as two chars ? Is there any easy and stylish way to solve this ?

Eg :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main()
{
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "ok" << "ok" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "test.." << "ok again" << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::left << std::setw(10) << "®èé" << "fail" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Ouputs :

```
ok        ok
test..    ok again
®èé    fail
```

Here is the live test : http://ideone.com/q57I0H

Comment: Use std::wcout for wide characters output

Comment: I guess you are using utf8 encoding. there is a related bug in gcc. check here: http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=33852.   You can convert all your strings to wchar_t, and use wcout.

Comment: *"easy and stylish..."* C++ doesn't have such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

They **are** two characters, check the value of `sizeof("®èé")`

Edit: since a commenter is confused about this: the definition of "character" used by `std::ostream` is `char`, not what Unicode calls a character (which might be represented by multiple code units in a variable-length encoding such as UTF-8). One byte to one character, always. You can use `std::ostream` to output a sequence of bytes which can then be interpreted as UTF-8 by some other consumer (something reading from a file or pipe, or displayed on the terminal), but the `ostream` itself knows nothing about UTF-8 and just transports the bytes from one place to another. Any members of `ostream` that depend on the number of characters (such as determining padding based on a specified width) will work with bytes *only*.

If you want Unicode-aware formatting, you can use `std::format` (since C++20) and `std::print` (since C++23).

As of mid-December 2023, GCC doesn't yet handle multibyte characters in `std::format`, because I haven't implemented [P2675](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2023/p2675r1.pdf) yet. As it happens, I was going to work on that today ...

Comment: They are two bytes, but only one character.

Comment: No, because the definition of "character" used by `std::ostream` is `char`. It's not Unicode-aware.

Comment: The questions is not about character as defined in std::ostream but about character as defined in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_(computing) :). 
The example makes this clear.

Comment: The question is why does the iostream manipulator `std::setw` consider it to be two chars, and that is obviously dependent on how `std::ostream` defines it. Because the code uses `ostream`. So that's what matters. I'm not sure what part of that is unclear.

Comment: You're right, how could I miss that? Sorry.